# Removing file extension before adding to listBox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I'm currently creating a note taking application. I'm trying to add items to a listbox without their file extensions, I have tried GetAllFilesWithoutExtensions, but no luck.  I'm currently able to add them but can't seem to remove the extension. Any advice would be greatly appreciated...

```
 DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("../Debug/");
 FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.txt");

 foreach (FileInfo file in files)
 {
    listBox1.Items.Add(file);
 }
```

Comment: have you tried this? `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)`

Comment: Hi @Nikola.Lukovic, Yes I have, unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Comment: can you show us what output you get when you run `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)` ?

Comment: Ok, when "Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name)" is used, the program is unable to load the associated .txt files into a richTextBox...  Which works with the extension... I suppose I'm just wanting to hide the extension.

Comment: This __use__ of the `ListBox` should have been in the original question; then you wouldn't have gotten all those answers that are rigth to the letter but missing the point ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You can use LINQ and [`System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension.aspx)

```
var fileNamesWithoutExtension = files
    .Select(fi => System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fi.Name));
foreach(string fn in fileNamesWithoutExtension)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(string)`

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getfilenamewithoutextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class to help you:

```
class FInfo
{
    public FileInfo Info { get; set; }

    public FInfo (FileInfo fi)    { Info = fi; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(Info.FullName);
    }
}
```

Now fill the `ListBox` with instances of that class:

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(yourPath);
FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles(yourFilter);

foreach (FileInfo file in files) listBox1.Items.Add(new FInfo(file));
```

Now you can access the full `FileInfo` data:

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FInfo fi = listBox1.SelectedItem as FInfo;
    if (fi != null) Console.WriteLine(fi.Info.FullName); // do your thing here!
}
```

And the `ListBox` will use the `ToString` method to display only the file names without path or extension..